# A planet with a different water:land ratio and

Tags: science-based, alternate-worlds

I'm drafting a world for my first fantasy series and I am using human beings as the main species.

Would there be any issue with people being trapped on a planet for a long period of time without modern technology (say 700-1000 years), which is only 29% water-covered and 71% land-covered?

EDITED TO PROVIDE MORE INFO:

People crashed/arrived within 100km of main body of water. They have some resources, tents, first aid kits, small food stocks, but nothing you`d expect outside of a school or residential building. Starting population is 5,000,000 (which should be sufficient to avoid in-breeding).

The temperature was between 10 and 40 Celsius in the area they arrived for at least 1 year. Planet is 70% the volume of earth and 80% the mass (core has less silicon and more lead). The majority of the planet is more desert like than earth, but it does have a small jungle and other flora heavy regions. As far as food, there is a moderate amount of fruits and edible plants, but virtually no large fauna - mostly edible rodents.

If there was an issue, would it merely life difficult, or would it make their extinction likely?

Thanks in advance.
SGCG

Comment: But we don't know the weather, or where the ship landed, or if they had anything, or much about this planet or these people at all.

Comment: Fair point: I'll update my OP.

Comment: Hi and congratulations to your first question. First, it is really hard to predict what will happen in 700-1000 years to a group. Also, many weather-effects will highly depend on the land-layout, clima-zones, ect. Look at typical weather cells here on earth, for example around/above central asia, northern russia, west-coast of south-america, the creation of hurricans, the golf-stream. My point is, you should be able to create any weather you like, and as such this question it is too broad. (However, you can fix it with more info, eg. latitude, distance-to-sea, water currents, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The climate would be very different, and possibly the ecosphere as well.

- Areas deeply inland will have little rain and little water. That means not much plant life and a reduced oxygen production. Sea life might not be able to compensate because there is so little of it.
- Some areas at the coasts will have rain, for hundreds or thousands of miles inland. Prople can live there.
- Oceans are buffers for temperature changes, CO2, salts, ...
- Are the oceans connected? If not, there could be completely different ecosystems in the separate parts.

Summarized, a much harsher world, but possibly livable. Climate science is complicated enough to prevent easy predictions. (Or to put it the other way around, climate science is complicated enough that you can justify habitable spots.)